# SSRS and a stuborn Excel Serial Date

Tags: reporting-services

Sorry Guys, I need some help doing this for a datefield in SSRS. I have a spreadsheet that I export as an xml file, then use that xml as a datasource for my dataset in SSRS. The field for the date comes through as 42969 instead of a Date  22/08/2017. I am not sure how to convert this in ssrs to a date using an expression. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Why the down votes? If seems a perfectly reasonable question. If you want to vote down at least suggest to this new SO user what's wrong with the question.

Comment: Thank you Alan, I really appreciate the response. I was finding a million answers on how to do iy in SQL but none as an expression in SSRS. I will test the solution now and let you know how I manage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert this quiet simply but as the data has come from Excel you need to adjust the date by 2 (Excel and SSRS/VB.NET treat serial dates differently).

The following should work

```
=DateAdd("d", Fields!MyDateField.Value -2, "1900-01-01")
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much for the help.